# How To Call Variable Name From Another Class C#

Tags: c#, class, oop

Example of the code

```
class Main{
        Name Jack = new Name();
        Jack.Speak();
}

class Name{
     public string speak(){
        Console.WriteLine("Hello", valuename);
      }
      
     public Name()
     {
       valuename = nameof(Jack); 
     }
}
```

Output the what im searching for:

```
Hello Jack.
```

If user types `Name Joe = new Name();` output will be `Hello Joe.`

Comment: within class Name, the variable `jack` you are trying to reference in `public Name()` is out of scope

Comment: There is no mechanism in C# that allows an object to access it's variable name. You can imagine that if such a behavior existed, it would cause serious problems if you were to, for example, pass your `Name` object into a Method which uses a different variable name.

Comment: Consider `var Jack = new Name(): var Bill = Jack;`. An object has properties and identity, but it doesn't have a clue about the variables that refer to it. And, as @Ryan mentioned, variables have scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variable names are syntactical sugar that is mostly thrown away by the compiler, so there's no direct way to do this.

The closest you can get is using [`[CallerArgumentExpression]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0) to have the compiler capture the source code expression that was passed to a parameter, but this only works for method arguments and will capture the entire expression, not just the variable name. For example, the following program will print `jack` then `jack + "hello"`:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        var jack = "dummy";
        WriteExpression(jack);
        WriteExpression(jack + "hello");
    }

    static void WriteExpression(
        string param, 
        [CallerArgumentExpression("param")] string paramExpression = null
    ) => Console.WriteLine(paramExpression);
}
```